# Zim Wiki - Linux - How to change code block color scheme

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using dark theme for Zim on Ubuntu 20. The application theme looks OK but the code block color scheme is not right. I cannot find a way to change the **Color Scheme** (different from setting individual colors in styles.conf for ~/.config/zim/styles.conf). I cannot find a way in Zim configuration to change the Color Scheme.

Currently it appears that the code block is using the "Default" color scheme that can also be found in Gedit.

[image]

I can change the Gedit color scheme easily but the fact that both Zim and Gedit use same color scheme by default leads me to believe there should be an OS/User level setting that dictates this default behavior?

I want to switch Zim codeblock color scheme to, say, Cobalt. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the color scheme for code blocks within Zim.

Edit-->Preferences-->Plugins-->Source View

Then click the "Configure" button below the right-side pane.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I checked the source view plugin configuration but I couldn't find a setting to change color scheme.